# Is it possible to create "C" statements at run time and execute them?

Tags: c

My Problem:

- Program takes input from a file { INFINITE, CMDSTART, 2, CMDPLAY, 4, CMDPAUSE, CMDSTOP }
- Any combination of the above input commands is possible.
- Output of the program is to read the above input and execute the functions in the order defined by the input.
- Above input should result in a executing a code something like:

  ```
  while(true)
  {
      cmdStart();
      for(i=0;i<2;++i)
          cmdPlay();
      for(i=0;i<4;++i)
          cmdPause();
      cmdStop();
  }
  ```

If I didnt have "INFINITE", then probably I would have had a `strcmp()` and a switch statement to get the order of execution. But with infinite, I realized, I have to store these function pointers in a array in the input order. After that, within a while(loop), I have to call these function pointers. Any interesting thoughts about how else to do this.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I don't think your prof would assign you homework that's impossible right? Also infinite could just be a while(true) loop.

Comment: Are you talking about c or c++? They are not the same language, and you probably should not tag them both. (Unless your question involves using the two languages in some way)

Comment: What is the significance of "INFINITE"?

Comment: Is it combination or permutation of the commands?  What are the alternatives to INFINITE?

Comment: If you think that dynamically generating code to do something like this is an acceptable solution then you've got problems.

Comment: This gets to be a harder problem when you consider input in the form `{INFINITE, 2, INFINITE, CMDPLAY}`. What does the for loop for the command `2` act over?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to solve your problem, whatever it is?  Could you describe what in general you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the information from the file into an array of structures which describe the iteration count and the function to be called.  You then have some code that interprets the structures and acts accordingly.

Actually generating C code at run time is possible, but tough enough that I wouldn't bother.  You'd probably write the C code to a source file, compile it into a dynamically loaded library, and then load the library before executing it.  A phrase about 'sledgehammers' and 'nuts' springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need a compiler (or two) to do it. Basically, you'll need to translate your "mini-language" into C, then invoke a C compiler to compile the result, and then execute that. You're (apparently) expecting that to execute in the context of the parent program, so to execute it you'll typically want to load it as a shared library or DLL or whatever your platform provides along that line.

IMO, this is a fairly roundabout way to accomplish what you're after though. It's much more common to embed some sort of script interpreter (e.g., [lua](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-embed-lua/index.html)) into your executable, and write scripts in that language.